# Pointer and variable sized array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new in c++. I don't clearly understand the line:
`int** outer = new int*[n];`
.

I took from solution here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/editorial

And the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem

Many thanks!

Comment: And what do you not understand about it?

Comment: why before [n] have * and outer have 2 *. ty

Comment: `int**` means "a pointer to a pointer to `int`" - presumably it is used to implement a dynamic 2-dimensional array. Though in practice there are way better ways to achieve this (such as using `std::vector`)

Comment: Could also be that you just want a pointer to an `int[]`.

Comment: Thank you! But can you speak more deeply about the heap, or what that line really do with the memory? I'm trying to understand cleary about this, i'm really confusing about the pointer.

Comment: This is not a useful question for SO. Try any half-decent C++ book or tutorial.

Comment: OK. Thank you underscore_d i ll try

Comment: @TrippKinetics a pointer to an `int[]` is an `int (*)[]`, not an `int**`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm new in c++. I don't clearly understand the line: int** outer = new
>   int*[n];

It means you allocate memory to store an array of n elements of type "pointer to an integer".

As operator `new` returns a pointer to the first element, `outer` variable is of type `int **` which means here "a pointer to a pointer to an integer"

This answer might also help you to understand :

[How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: ty, it does help. But can you speak more deeply about the heap, or what that line really do with the memory? I'm trying to understand cleary about this, i'm really confusing about the pointer.

Comment: Forget the heap for the moment. It is not necessary to understand pointers, and the compiler may not even use it. When you read about dynamic allocation in the heap, just mentally replace "heap" with "dynamic memory space", which is probably the term they should be using.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't clearly understand the line: `int** outer = new int*[n];`

In such cases it could be useful to use type alias:

```
using intp = int *;
intp *outer = new intp[n];
```

so you have a dynamically allocated array of type `intp`, thing that `intp` is a pointer as well should not confuse you and having type alias can help to understand that.